# Cleaning up keypress event listener with "this" context

Tags: reactjs

I have an event handler that needs access to the React component (this) in order to use `this.setState()`. After removing the component I want the event handler to be garbage collected.

I'm asking myself if there's a better way than my current setup:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // Preserve this context
        this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return <div></div>;
    }

    handleKeyDown() {
        // this.setState(...);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        window.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyDown);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        // Clean up
        window.removeEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyDown);
    }
};
```

**EDIT**

It's especially this line that seems a bit hacky to me:

```
// Preserve this context
this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this);
```

Comment: Not sure what your application is, but I don't see anything wrong with this implementation. What don't you like about it?

Comment: I've pointed it out a bit more clear, can you reload the page?

Comment: I don't understand that line. Are you trying to pass `this` to your `handleKeyDown()`?

Comment: Yes, to be able to use `this.setState()`, otherwise `this` would be `Window`. This is what I want to know: Is there cleaner way to do this?

Comment: That's weird. Try to use `handleKeyDown = () => { this.setState(); }` instead, and remove `this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this);`

Comment: So `handleKeyDown` is a private variable somewhere?

Comment: it's a reference to a function. It's ES6 syntax. Did it work?

Comment: Not sure if I got the point, how do you clean it up afterwards? Can you copy my code above and edit it the way you propose?

Comment: Do you mean this: `window.addEventListener(this.handleKeyDown = () => { this.setState(...) }`?

Comment: `this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this);` is not hacky and does exactly what it is expected to do: preserve `this` context. When passing a function to a child component you don't want to bind in the props because it will force a rerender every single time (`.bind` returns a new function every single time it's called so React thinks props changed). It doesn't really matter in the code snippet you showed but it's a good idea in general to always bind in the constructor.

Comment: The way you're doing it is the standardized way since React moving to ES6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion (see questions comments) it was agreed that this way is totally okay:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // Preserve this context
        this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return <div></div>;
    }

    handleKeyDown() {
        // this.setState(...);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        window.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyDown);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        // Clean up
        window.removeEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyDown);
    }
};
```